# SKSpriteNode removeFromParent in touchesEnded

Tags: sprite-kit, touches, skspritenode

I have an issue removing an SKSpriteNode from it's parent when a touch is detected on that SKSpriteNode. Here is the code:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint sceneLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        if ([_tableDoneButton containsPoint:sceneLocation]) {
            NSLog(@"here");
            [self removeItemsFromView];
            _headerNode.portLabel.text = [IPGameManager sharedGameData].world.player.port.name;
            [_portNode show];
        }

        SKNode *nodeInPort = [_portNode nodeAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:_portNode]];
        if ([nodeInPort.name isEqualToString:@"marketButton"]) {
            [self showMarket];
        }
    }
}
```

In the `showMarket` function, a 'Done' `SKSpriteNode` is added so the user can leave the market when he/she wants to. As you can see above, if the `_tableDoneButton` contains the touch location, it should call the `removeItemsFromView` function which contains `[_tableDoneButton removeFromParent];`. Do I have to do something special when removing nodes this way?

Another issue: It seems to get removed ~1 second later. What exactly happens when you run `[node removeFromParent]`? If I set the SKSpriteNode to nil after I call `[self removeItemsFromView]` it works fine. But I shouldn't have to do that?

Comment: Try calling `[_tableDoneButton removeFromParent];` here directly instead of `[self removeItemsFromView];` and see if anything changes. You could also try processing these touches in `-(void)touchesBegan:`. Whenever I call `removeFromParent` the effect is immediately visible.
Also: add a `continue;` line after `[_portNode show];` to avoid processing the same touch for the marketButton.

Comment: Calling `[_tableDoneButton removeFromParent];` there directly instead of the function yields the same issue. I wonder if it's a simulator issue? Although I've never had this issue before.